# $onChanges doesn't update value on initialization of component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hey I have a component which have two bindings values:load & max.
I am initialize the load and max in $onInit method with values:

load: 0 
max: 300.

and then I changed the value of the component using $onChange cycle which need to update the value of load to 100.

But this doesn't happen, I am only get the initialize values which has been set in $onInit and not the last value which has been set in $onChanges.
I can see using the console.log, that the value has been update but I can't see it on the UI(template of component).

Can someone explain to me what is the problem and how to solve it?

Here is the code which I am talking about:
http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/JEVWbO

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
  <load load="loadData" max="maxData"></load>
</div>

var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("mainCTRL",function($scope){
  $scope.loadData = 100;
  $scope.maxData  = 500;
})
app.component("load",{
    template:'<div><span>{{$ctrl.load}}</span> <span>{{$ctrl.max}}</span></div>',
    controller: loadController,
    bindings: {
        load: '<',
        max: '<'
    }
})

function loadController(){
  var self = this;
  self.$onInit  = function(){
    self.load = 0;
    self.max = 300;
  }

  self.$onChanges = function(changes){
    self.load = changes.load.currentValue;
    console.log('onChanges self.load',self.load);
   }

}
```

Comment: no.. it isn't copy and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$onInit()` is called after all bindings have been initialized. It means in your `$onInit` method, `self.load` has already been set to 100 and you overwrite it with 0. Try:

```
  self.$onInit  = function(){
    self.load = self.load || 0;
    self.max = self.max || 300;
  }
```

One more interesting thing: `$onChanges` is called before `$onInit`. Here is a discussion [why](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14433).